# What does "stuff it in the back right corner" mean?

Tags: landing, pilot-technique, tail-dragger

I'm still catching up with Flightchops, and came across [this episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVhtOMeiZ4M) about his first tail wheel solo.  As he touches down for his first landing (around 5:03 in the video) he says "Get ready to stuff it in the back right corner".  He says it again a few seconds later.

I am low time in tail draggers (about 3 hours post endorsement) and I don't remember ever hearing my instructor use this phraseology.

### Question:

What does he mean by this?  Is this common aviation terminology or just something he picked up from his instructor?

I can make an educated guess that he means to deflect the stick to the rear and right to allow for a three point landing with a right x-wind, but I'd love to get confirmation of this from the experts.

Note: I did [google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Stuff+it+in+the+back+right+corner&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=active&q=Stuff+it+in+the+back+right+corner+aviation), and came up blank.

Comment: +1 just for googling before posting, and your educated guess.

Comment: Hm...I'll have to mention that more often in my questions.  I always research before posting...I thought I might get flicked for ONLY googling ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't a standard aviation term, it's just a casual phrase that he's using to emphasize or remind himself about the stick movement he needs. It's like your instructor telling you to "get dancing" on the rudder pedals: it's not an aviation term as such, but it's a very clear, descriptive reminder.

In a three-point landing you pull the stick all the way back after touchdown to keep the tail down. That helps to prevent unwanted pitch movements and gets weight on the tailwheel to help with directional control on the ground (as airspeed decreases and the rudder loses authority). Deflecting the stick to the right would be because of a crosswind from the right. Put those two things together, and the required stick movement is back and to the right, which is one "corner" of the range of motion it has.